How to listen to newLine ime action in TextField in Android? (Using Jetpack Compose)
I have a textField in which I want to listen to the newLine(Enter) and perform action accordingly.
I didn't find any dedicated action button for this specific purpose.
I tried using onKeyEvent but found out this is for the Hardware keyboard only. However, it did listen to the Key.Backspace but didn't listen for Key.Enter
                OutlinedTextField(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .onKeyEvent { // For hardware keyboard
                            if (it.key == Key.Enter) {
                                if (text.isNotBlank()) {
                                    showCheckListTitle = true
                                    viewModel.addListItem(index + 1, "")
                                }
                            },
                    keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions.Default.copy(
                        keyboardType = KeyboardType.Text
                    ),
                    keyboardActions = KeyboardActions(onAny = {
                        // Could not get it listened
                        Log.d("ListenToEnter", this.toString())
                    })

When using the other imeAction like ImeAction.Default I could not perform any keyboardActions neither it listens using onAny (as shown in above code).
Other actions like Done, Next, Previous, Send, Search doesnot fit the purpose as it does not show Enter in the imeAction button.
What I want to achieve is, I want to listen to the enter/new line in the textField so that i can perform action accordingly.
The Enter ime button,


User types some text in the textfield, after pressing Enter key or Done in the software keyboard we perform some action and clear the focus for text field.
val focusManager = LocalFocusManager.current

OutlinedTextField(
    value = text,
    onValueChange = {
        text = it.replace("\n", "")
    },

    // preventing \n or enter key from the keyboard
    singleLine = true,
    keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions.Default.copy(
        keyboardType = KeyboardType.Text,
        imeAction = ImeAction.Done
    ),
    keyboardActions = KeyboardActions(
        onDone = {
            // perform some action
            focusManager.clearFocus()
        }
    ),
    modifier = Modifier
        .onKeyEvent { event -> // For hardware keyboard
            if (event.key == Key.Enter) {
                if (text.isNotBlank()) {
                    // perform some action

                    focusManager.clearFocus()
                    // to stop propagation of this event.
                    return@onKeyEvent true
                }
            }
            return@onKeyEvent false
        }
)


Thank you for your effort, but I want to perform actions inside lambda (something like incrementing the variable) when the enter key is pressed while typing in textField. Done action has a checkmark for ime indication so I cannot use it as I am strictly looking for action to be done when Enter is pressed.
For a little contrast I have added the image just clarify the ime button.

@CuriousHead what is your use case for this approach. for example user enter some text and press enter then add item to list then clear text in textfield. Or any other use case

It's something like,
I want to listen to the Enter in the TextField. Whenever Enter is pressed, I want to increment a variable (+1) which is remembered so that its increment adds a Composable i.e. another TextField (just for understanding).
So, what I want to do is listen to the ime Enter key so that I can trigger actions accordingly.
